# Trouble with join in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, join

In my rails app, I have a filter which shows all the jobs based on parameters passed into my scopes which all works fine, but as an extension to that, I have an ajax call that limits the jobs you can pick based on the projects and clients you select in the filter. Here are my relationships:

A client has many projects 
A project belongs to a client and has many jobs 
A Job belongs to a project

I can list all the projects based on the client and all the jobs based on a project, but what I am having trouble with is listing all the jobs when just a client is specified, so, getting all the projects for that client and then getting all the jobs for all those projects.

I'm guessing I have to use a join to get this to work, but have tried for a couple of days with no luck :(

If anyone could point me in the direction of a good resource I can look over to try solve this problem it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hopefully useful: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed and now working. Thanks heaps sarnold :)

Comment: Excellent; if you wouldn't mind sketching quickly the before-and-after in an answer for others. (I don't recall the feature well enough to write a _good_ answer, but I did have the link handy.)

Comment: Yep will do, just have to wait a few hours I don't have enough rep yet :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before this feature worked models looked as follows -

```
    class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :projects

    end

    class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :client
      has_many :jobs

    end

    class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :project

    end
```

In order to get Jobs based only on a client, a has_many through relationship had to be set up in the client model.

```
    class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :projects
      has-many :jobs, :through => :projects

    end
```

Then in your controller, you can get all the jobs through the client id by using this new relationship -

```
    @jobs = Client.find(params[:id]).jobs
```

which will return all the jobs for the client that it finds. Once again thanks to sarnold for the link to the guide that got me to this solution